# Wrong order of fetched data from Firestore (Vue.js)

Tags: sorting, vue.js, datatable, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from Firestore *COLLECTION A*, where are IDs of users (*createdBy* and *lastUpdateBy*). Users data (firstName, surName...) are in *COLLECTION B*. If I fetch data from Firestore and use OrderBy lastUpdateBy, **the order is firstly by USER** (from the newest to the oldest), after that by lastUpdateAt, as I just want. Please, can you help me, what is wrong?

```
  // Fetch Data from the Firestore

  let refUsers = db.collection('users')
  db.collection('campTypes').orderBy("lastUpdateAt", "asc")
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {

    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      refUsers.doc(change.doc.data().createdBy).get()
      .then(createdByUser => {
        var cbUser = createdByUser.data()

        refUsers.doc(change.doc.data().lastUpdateBy).get()
        .then(updatedByUser => {
          var ubUser = updatedByUser.data()

          if(change.type === 'added') {
            this.campTypes.unshift({
              id: change.doc.id,
              name: change.doc.data().name,
              status: change.doc.data().status, 
              createdAt: change.doc.data().createdAt, 
              createdBy: change.doc.data().createdBy, 
              createdByUser: cbUser,
              lastUpdateAt: change.doc.data().lastUpdateAt,
              lastUpdateBy: change.doc.data().lastUpdateBy, 
              lastUpdateByUser: ubUser
            })
          }


        })

      })
    })
  })
```

[Image: Datatable, where the newest update isn't on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9zPl.png)

Comment: you mentioned that you are expecting to order by "lastUpdateBy" but the only orderby I see there is ordering by "lastUpdateAt", is this the correct snipped code? Also, have you tried printing the resulted object after you get the data ordered? The screenshot you shared shows the data after it has been rendered on the UI, so the issue could also be lying on the generation of that HTML part, in order to rule that out it would be good to share the resulting object after the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry, I want to order by "lastUpdateAt", so at the top should be the newest data, but there are firstly data from the newest user (newest by creating in Firestore) and at each user is order by "lastUpdateAt". I don't want to order data by user, only exactly by time of updating. The resulting objects after the query are the same as the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, could you also provide an overview of the schema that is in place, from the description I understand there's two collections, usually for complex queries you would need to configure [indexes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) on your Datastore. Do you have any index for this query in place?